# analyze text files

Tags: java, android, file, text

I have a noob question.

My java project analyzes text files.

There are `three ways` that the data can appear:

```
1. Search-term-A: data-to-collect-A

2. data-to-collect-B,  search-term-B

3. data-to-collect-C@search-term-C
```

I manage to collect all relevant lines by finding the search term inside. I did this by implementing `grep` in my app.

But I don’t know how to extract the three `data-to-collect` parameters.

Thanks, 
Andy.

Comment: Why you have to use Android tag?with your Question?if your project is java project.there is too much difference actually totally both are different projects Please specifically ask your question don't confuse us Thanks

Comment: well, I am writing this for Android...

Comment: this is actually line = bufferedReader.readLine()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm assuming you have following text in your.txt file

```
My First Line,My Second Line,My 3rd Line
```

Code is

```
String line="";
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] yourLinesOneByOne = line.split(",");
    String[] itemofLine = yourLinesOneByOne[0].split(" ");//within "Space" 
    //itemofLine[0] has "My"
    //itemofLine[1] has "First"
    //itemofLine[2] has "Line"

}
```

Comment: String.split() returns a String[] array. Moreover, the question asks how to separate the items within a single line.

Comment: what if the line "my first line," contains four, five or sometimes six words? how can I count the number of items that line.split produce? thanks guys.

Comment: by getting size of itemofLine

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've got the line as a String, the easiest way would be to use, split() function.

For the first type:

```
String line; //Your line 
String[] items=line.split(":");
```

Now, items[1] would give you the data-to-collect.

Similarly, for the other two types, you'd use,

```
line.split(",");
line.split("@");
```

I'm also assuming the characters , @ and : do not come as part of the search-string and the data-to-collect.

Hope this helps!!